# pgadmin4 can't connect to postgres running over Rocky Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, database-administration

The postgres is running on `Rocky Linux 8.5`:

```sh
sudo systemctl status postgresql-14
● postgresql-14.service - PostgreSQL 14 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-14.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/postgresql-14.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-03-10 04:31:09 GMT; 16min ago
     Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/static/
  Process: 67527 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-14/bin/postgresql-14-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 67534 (postmaster)
    Tasks: 8 (limit: 101066)
   Memory: 18.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql-14.service
           ├─67534 /usr/pgsql-14/bin/postmaster -D /mnt/data/db-rocky-primary/data
           ├─67536 postgres: logger
           ├─67538 postgres: checkpointer
           ├─67539 postgres: background writer
           ├─67540 postgres: walwriter
           ├─67541 postgres: autovacuum launcher
           ├─67542 postgres: stats collector
           └─67543 postgres: logical replication launcher

Mar 10 04:31:08 db-primary-rocky systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 14 database server...
Mar 10 04:31:09 db-primary-rocky postmaster[67534]: 2022-03-10 04:31:09.590 GMT [67534] LOG:  redirecting log output to logging collector process
Mar 10 04:31:09 db-primary-rocky postmaster[67534]: 2022-03-10 04:31:09.590 GMT [67534] HINT:  Future log output will appear in directory "log".
Mar 10 04:31:09 db-primary-rocky systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL 14 database server.
```

I can connect to it with no issues when on the box:

```sql
psql
psql (14.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \conninfo
You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".
```

I have added this to the `pg_hba.conf` file:

```sh
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          trust
```

I have also changed the following in the `postgresql.conf` file and `restarted the server`:

```sh
listen_addresses = '*'
```

why I can't connect to it via pgadmin4? I am sitting in the `192.168.1.0/24` network and the PostgreSQL running in 192.168.1.0/24 network.

Both networks can ping each other. The pgadmin4 gives `connection refused` error. I am not sure why?
what am I missing?

thanks

Comment: SELinux or firewall on your DB linux blocking connexions?  What do psql logs say?  Do you see the connection attempt on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

As per @Nic3500 comment, that's how I fixed it:

check if postgres is listening on the designated port:

```sh
sudo netstat -nltp
```

Now check if firewall is enabled:

```sh
systemctl status firewalld
OR
sudo firewall-cmd --state
```

if the service is active and running then simply do the following:

```sh
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service=postgresql
```

Make the settings permanent:

```sh
sudo firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent
```

Now you can connect with no issues